# Experimental justification for modelling electron as point instead of charged shell?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

Down to what size is there experimental justification for modelling the electron as a point like particle without volume? Asked in another way, at what size scale would it be more correct to model the electron as a charged shell with unknown internal structure instead of a geometric point without volume?

[I am not questioning whether or not the model is correct - only where the cutoff between theory and proof should be drawn when evaluating alternative theories]

**EDIT**  The proposed duplicate question does not contain any answers that would suggest a 'proven maximum size' like I am asking about.

Comment: Where among the answers to that other question is there a numerical value that is related to my question?

Comment: @user263399 In what case would anyone find themselves "modeling the electron as a charged shell with unknown internal structure"? How would one test such a model? (All of the electron-compositeness-scale/electron-radius tests I know of, for example in the PDG: http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-searches-quark-lep-compositeness.pdf, require some model for how the internal structure works.)

Comment: I'm reading http://www.cybsoc.org/electron.pdf which toys with electrons being photons confined within a toroidal topology or some such (haven't finished yet) - but in such a case one would expect deviation between the point and shell at some scale.

Comment: @user263399 But that's not a model in which the electron would be a charged shell with unknown internal structure. That's a model in which the electron has _known_ internal structure (and the proposed internal structure doesn't necessarily support a charged-shell interpretation, anyway).

Comment: but outside a shell of a specific radius and with a specific surface charge it would be indistinguishable when replaced by a point charge at its centre

Comment: I don't think there is any experimental evidence of the electron not being a point particle, right? (Note, particle physics is not my area of expertise)

Comment: @AaronStevens - that is correct. All attempts to find a scattering interaction that does not allow for a point-like electron have had a null result. I've lost track of the current experimental bounds on the largest possible size, but its darned small...

Comment: Current experimental limit seems to be that the electron is smaller than $10^{-18}m$ in radius.

Comment: @JonCuster - do you have a source for that number please?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature10104 would be a place to start.